# Where do Thrift's SDK files come from?

Tags: objective-c, thrift, arm64

I'm working with a project that has used Thrift in the past to generate an client server architecture in Objective C.  I understand the concept of using Thrift IDL to generate service endpoints, but I'm confused as to where the base SDK files come from (e.g. TBinaryProtocol).

The build is set up just to run the Thrift compiler on any .thrift files and just generates the respective *IDL.m files.  I see that TBinaryProtocol is obviously used in many projects out there, and we have it as a static source file (not generated every build) so I'm guessing that it could have been generated or just provided from an open source repo, but I don't see any information about it generating it or finding those files.

In general, I need to either regenerate these files so that they're 64 bit compatible or update them from open source to 64 bit compatible versions.

EDIT:  With some extra Googling, I've come across a github project that may be the objective-c implementation, perhaps even where this code was imported form.  If anyone knows for sure whether or not this is the legitimate one, please let me know.

https://github.com/nathanmarz/thrift-dev/blob/master/lib/cocoa/src/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files are part of the Thrift framework itself, which is now a project of [the Apache Software Foundation](http://apache.org/). You can download the Thrift source code from [the project's website](http://thrift.apache.org/), which also has [instructions on accessing the official Git repository](http://thrift.apache.org/developers).